# Django - Where to write code for easy-thumnails custom THUMBNAIL_NAMER?

Tags: python, django, easy-thumbnails

I am working on a `Django` project using the wonderful `easy-thumbnails` plugin to generate thumbnails for images. I don't like how the thumbnails have the format of:

`source.jpg.100x100_q80_crop_upscale.jpg`

If my image is named `source.jpg`, I'd much rather have something like:

`source_thumb.jpg`.

Upon reading the plugin's docs (http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/settings/), I have discovered that there is a setting where I can set a custom `THUMBNAIL_NAMER`, which is essentially a function that returns the desired thumbnail string.

**My Question:**

Where is the proper place to define this function in my project? I want to maintain a logical and clean project structure, and am unsure where to place this function.

Thank you so much for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THUMBNAIL_NAMER` is a setting, and the default is

```
THUMBNAIL_NAMER = 'easy_thumbnails.namers.default'
```

which means, in the `easy_thumbnails` packages, a method named `default` in `namers.py`

Source code: https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/blob/master/easy_thumbnails/namers.py#L7

So, if you wish to override it, in your `settings.py`

```
THUMBNAIL_HELPER = '<myapp>.namers.default'
```

and then have the overriden definition of this method in the package `myapp` (any app that is in `INSTALLED_APPS` that would make most sense), in `namers.py` (well, it could be anything - just an example)

Since it is the thumbnail, if it is thumbnail associated with user's avatar, I would put it in the userprofile app.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would keeping my own namer function in `myapp/namers.py` be the best place? Or is there some common pattern among `django` users where they place such util functions in some other directory, perhaps `myapp/utils/` or `myapp/common/`?

Comment: well.. I would keep it simple and consistent with the third party application. But, yes - if you feel that is cleaner, go for it.